# Given @comments - how to exclude the first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

given `@comments = Comments.last(6)`, which queries based on the model's default named scope.

How can I essentially tell `Rails` to give me the last 6 records EXCLUDING the first record?
And if there are less than `6`, just give me as many up to `6` as possible, again excluding the first record?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :excluding_first, lambda {
    first = Comment.first
    return [] unless first
    where("id <> #{first.id}")
  }
end
```

Since scopes compose, you can then do:

```
Comment.excluding_first.last(6)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use brute-force rather than SQL magics here:

```
@comments.delete_at(0)
```